# Vagrant and Intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, vagrant

I'm starting with vagrant and created the Play Framework project in VM and now I do not know how to import the project into IntelliJ IDE, I need to do now.

vagrant ssh
play new app